# Which security rule should be used to restrict communication between two instances in the same network in Openstack?

Tags: openstack, instances, openstack-neutron

I've installed Openstack Queens v. in my CentOS VM. I'm trying to restrict the  communication between two instances in the same network. I know that a security rule can do it. Can any one tell me which rule should be used or we need to create a new one.